# trying to simulate lane change but receive change.m_TrajectoryCosts.size() Not Equal m_GeneratedRollOuts.size() error

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was trying to follow [these steps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_4rXvKPWMY) on autoware 1.12 installed from source on kinetic.

The shown version did not have the equivalent options in the Compute tab but I tried to do roughly the same.
(Can't upload image because not enough karma..)
https://imgur.com/a/1tZ9vJV

Rrqt_graph here
https://imgur.com/a/Hssn7k0

The error I receive is "m_TrajectoryCosts.size() Not Equal m_GeneratedRollOuts.size()" from /autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_planning/op_local_planner/nodes/op_trajectory_evaluator/op_trajectory_evaluator_core.cpp:TrajectoryEval::MainLoop:303

Because "m_TrajectoryCostsCalculator.m_TrajectoryCosts.size() == m_GeneratedRollOuts.size()" on row 284 is not true.
See https://pastebin.com/E4XViJuH

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332702/trying-to-simulate-lane-change-but-receive-change.m_trajectorycosts.size()-not-equal-m_generatedrollouts.size()-error/) by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2019-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaohongfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/52085/gaohongfei/) on 2020-02-26**:
have you solve it?

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-02-26**:
No, I stopped using autoware before I resolved it. See Hatems answer, I didn't attempt it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a complete feature (just proof of concept)
the working example is on old version.
to get the same results as the video using ver 1.12.
you need to use op_global_planner + op_local_planner instead of way_planner and dp_planner.
check the tutorial https://youtu.be/BS5nLtBsXPE

also don't forget to change one flag in op_planner -> MappingHelpers.h and MappingHelpers.cpp to enable the map loader to discover the adjacent lanes.

Regards,

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2019-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fantasyplus](https://answers.ros.org/users/57042/fantasyplus/) on 2020-08-05**:
did you mean the 'bFindLaneChangeLanes' flag in MappingHelpers.h?

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2020-08-06**:
Yes, this will enable calling a method that search the map for adjacent lanes.
if you have lane change information in the map, you don't need this option.

**Comment by [tutu](https://answers.ros.org/users/60297/tutu/) on 2020-10-31**:
still facing the same problem